# Minimum length of a commutator in a free group?

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $F_n$ be the free group on $n$ generators - if it makes no difference we can just stick with $F_2$.  I would like to show that the minimum length (in terms of the standard generating set) of an element in $[F_n,F_n]$ is 4.  More generally, is there any lower bound for $\ell([g,h])$ given the lengths $\ell(g)$ and $\ell(h)$?

One example I am keeping in mind is $[x,yx^n] = xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ so any sort of lower bound will probably have to maybe take some kind of minimum of $\ell(g)$ and $\ell(h)$.

Comment: The lower bound of $4$ comes by observing that $1$ and $3$ are impossible (since the exponent sum must be zero), and $2$ is impossible (since the exponent sum on each letter must be zero). I presume you mean a nontrivial element, so $0$ is also ruled out.